# Surface area of a flat surface that wraps a spherical cap

Tags: geometry, area, surfaces

Suppose that you wrap sphere in aluminum foil, much like how kisses, the candy, are wrapped. You would lay the sphere on a flat piece of aluminum foil, then you would collect the edges of the foil over the top of the sphere and cut off, or tie the excess(link to pictures provided below).

Now suppose that you to cut the sphere $h$ units from the bottom(diametrically opposite to the tied/cut end) so that the resulting shape would be spherical cap wrapped in aluminum foil. **What would the area of the unwrapped and straightened foil from the spherical cap be in terms of the radius, $r$, of the sphere and the height, $h$, of the cap?**

Here are [some pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7cxb.jpg) of this being done a lemon if it helps.

**Attempt:**
The lower bound for the area will be the surface area of the spherical cap(excluding the base) itself since the foil wrap the cap completely but still has creases and wrinkles on its surface, so $A > 2\pi h r$. I think an upper bound would be the area of a square with side length that is the perimeter of the dome(if I could call it that)(see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFHtP.jpg)), because if you try to wrap a hemisphere with a foil of such dimensions you still have some excess foil left to cut. So, $A < 4\left(\displaystyle\int_{-r}^{-r+h}{\left. \sqrt{1+\frac{{{x}^{2}}}{{{r}^{2}}-{{x}^{2}}}}dx\right.}\right)^2$

Comment: That is approximately correct. Since there is no unique way to wrap it up, the approximation remains.

Comment: Instead of the cube you could consider a cylinder of base radius $\rho$ and height $r\arcsin(\rho/r)$ (the latter being half of what you call the perimeter of the dome).

Comment: If your solid is the portion of the ball (of radius $r$ centered at the origin) where $z \geq h$, and if you use a disk of foil whose center lies at the center of the base of the sphere, the radius has to be at least $$R = \sqrt{r^{2} - h^{2}} + r\arccos\tfrac{h}{r},$$the sum of the radius of the base and the arc along the surface of the sphere, giving an area $\pi R^{2}$. Conversely, it appears a disk of this radius can be suitably creased in order to cover the truncated sphere.

Comment: @Aretino Just noticed I said cube in the post, I meant a _square_ with side length equal to the length of the arc along the surface of the cap. I don't see how a cylinder you described would work as a better upper bound.

Comment: @Narasimham Even if the there isn't a unique way to wrap it up, the area of any two wraps done the way described in the post should have be very close(right?). Isn't a better approximate possible?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Why did you add the radius of the base($\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$)? I was looking for the area of a wrap that wraps only the dome, not the base. The area of a disc who's diameter is the arc long the surface is the surface area of the dome itself(excluding the base)(I think)

Comment: Ah...I misunderstood your description and photographs. (For what it's worth, the area of a flat disk whose radius is the arc along the dome has strictly larger area than the dome because the sphere has positive Gaussian curvature. In the extreme case, the disk has radius $\pi$ and therefore area $\pi^{3}$, while the sphere has area $4\pi$.)

Comment: From ancient times it is known that  surface area exactly equals $ 2 \pi r h$ even for a truncated sphere without folds

Comment: Now I understand better what you are asking. Instead of a square, you could then use a circle with diameter equal to the side of the square.